# define enum or constant in mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb

I have say some constants / enumeration type

ProductType = {"MF", "ETF", "SPA"}

I have 2 or more collections where I need to provide ProductType. In relational schema design we define a master table of ProductTypes with columns prodtypeid, prodtypevalue. In other tables we refer productType using foreign key "prodtypeid". Mongo is a non relational db. what is the good way to deal this in mongo ?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has no concept of enums. What I do is enforce the enums\constants in the application layer. In the node.js eco-system, for example, the [mongoose library has an enum enforcing feature](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators).